# Jquery: Fadeout(), fadein() e chamada Ajax não funcionam no tempo certo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, transição

Olá. Tenho esse código em JQuery:

```
$('#prods').fadeOut(300, function(event){
     chamaM(id_m);                            
});
$('#prods').fadeIn(300);
```

`ChamaM()` é uma função AJAX que faz uma chamada ao código PHP, exibindo o conteúdo dentro da `div #prods`.
Está tudo funcionando, mas o que está acontecendo é que quando o fadeout se completa o conteúdo anterior continuá lá, assim, o `fadeout()` e `fadein()` acontecem no conteúdo atual e só depois ele carrega o novo conteúdo. No ambiente de teste(XAMPP) tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas no servidor do site acontece esse erro.
O endereço, para que vcs possam visualizar é:  [www.lumiledbrasil.com.br/produtos.php](http://www.lumiledbrasil.com.br/produtos.php)

Já tentei algumas variações de funções e ordem das mesmas, mas sem sucesso.
Alguém pode me ajudar? Achei que só esse código era necessário. Se precisarem de mais informações, é só avisar. Agradeço imensamente a todos!

Comment: Ele pisca o produto que estava em foco antes de passar para o clicado, isso? Acho que não tem a ver com isso, acho que o `$('#prods').fadeIn(300);` tem que fazer parte da função logo após o AJAX ou até mesmo dentro do próprio AJAX como return.

Comment: é o que acontece sim. Se vc reparar, o que ele faz é dar o fadeout(), e começar o fadein() no conteúdo que já estava em foco. Só então ele carrega o novo conteúdo, sem o fadein(). Acredito que tenha algo a ver com a velocidade com que o Ajax ou Jquery avaliam as funções. Mas não consigo achar a solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só para complementar a resposta do @helderburato, para resolver o seu problema de footer, visto que a sua `<div id="prod-container" ...` tem uma altura mínima de 350px, você pode colocar uma div para *abraçar* a mesma com esta altura mínima ...

```
<div class="todooconteudo" style="min-height:350px">
     <div id="prod-container">
          // Seus produtos aqui
     </div>
</div>
```

Assim vai manter o footer aonde ele tem que ficar porque a div que encapsula o conteúdo da div dinâmica tem um min-height, uma propriedade do css.

**Sucessooooooooo ....**

Comment: FOI! Vlw!! Ficou perfeito

Comment: Se adicionar isso `width:100%; overflow:hidden` no elemento body na folha de estilo `estilo_lumiled.css`, some a barra de rolagem horizontal que não é nada bonito ficar ali.

Comment: Eu acho que você deveria editar a resposta dele e incluir esses detalhes. Sua resposta oor si só não responde a pergunta. Nem sei pq foi aceita.

Answer (score 2):

Tente dessa forma, creio que irá funcionar, você da o **fadeOut()**, remove o html de dentro da tag **#prods**, e quando o resultado for obtido pela chamada ajax, insere o resultado na tag que está oculta e da o **fadeIn()** para mostra-la:

```
$('#prods').fadeOut(300, function(event){
    $(this).html("");
    chamaM(id_m);                            
});

function chamaM(id_chamado){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'scriptPHP.php',
        data: 'id=' + id_chamado,
        success: function(data){
            if (data) {
                $('#prods').html(data).fadeIn(300);
            };
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: A ideia de vcs funciona, o único problema é que por um instante, entre o carregamento do conteúdo, a página fica sem conteúdo nenhum, o que faz o footer subir. Mas já é alguma coisa, vou continuar tentando a partir disso.